# Require unknown module "undefined". if you are sre the module exists, try restarting Metro in react-native(expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

In my app I am getting this error don't know why. I already tried reinstall node_modules but error is still exist [image: error image what i see on my phone]

[image: my all dependencies]

Comment: can you add error text here

Comment: Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`.

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10065#issuecomment-950192983

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** :

This can be fixed by installing react-native-screens

```
npm install react-native-screens
```

or

```
yarn add react-native-screens
```

**Solution 2** :

I had the same issue, so I used https://github.com/fattahmuhyiddeen/react-navigation-bottom-tabs so far it works

in my package.json:
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "fattahmuhyiddeen/react-navigation-bottom-tabs",

reference :  https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/10065#issuecomment-950192983

Comment: I have tried by installing react-native-screens but the error remains actually when I installed bcryptjs for hashing user password from then I started getting this error

Answer (score 0):

This error occurres because bcryptjs couldn't decide whether or not you're running your code on Node.js or using a Web execution environment. When trying to generate a salt, it passes a check for Node.js and after that tries to require its `crypto` module which doesn't exist. In order for it to work properly you'd have to make some changes in package source code itself.

As for `2.4.3` version of bcryptjs, open up `bcrypt.js` file in `node_modules/bcryptjs/dist` folder, then find and modify `random` method like that:

```
function random(len) {
    try {
        if (randomFallback)
            return randomFallback(len); 
        else if (!randomFallback)
            throw Error("Neither WebCryptoAPI nor a crypto module is available. Use bcrypt.setRandomFallback to set an alternative");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

After that create your own fallback method using `expo-crypto` package to generate securely random values:

```
import * as Crypto from 'expo-crypto';

function fallback(bytesAmount) {
    const typedArray = new Uint8Array(bytesAmount);
    Crypto.getRandomValues(typedArray);
    return typedArray;
};
```

If you have some issues with `expo-crypto` package, like non-existing `getRandomValues` method, try to update `expo` package to the latest version.

Then call `bcrypt.setRandomFallback` method with `fallback` function passed as an argument:

```
bcrypt.setRandomFallback(fallback);
```

And after everything is done it should work correctly.